# Datagridview add / delete / modify / insert / Save from Database access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data.DataTable


Public Class Form1
'Change "C:\Users\Jimmy\Documents\Merchandise.accdb" to your database location
Dim connString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=C:\test.accdb"
Dim MyConn As OleDbConnection
Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
Dim ds As DataSet
Dim tables As DataTableCollection
Dim source1 As New BindingSource
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'ce code du load data marche nickel , c une alternative au boutton load
    Me.Table1TableAdapter.Fill(Me.TestDataSet.Table1)

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'load data 
    MyConn = New OleDbConnection
    MyConn.ConnectionString = connString
    ds = New DataSet
    tables = ds.Tables
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [Table1]", MyConn) 'Change items to your database name
    da.Fill(ds, "TestDataSet.Table1") 'Change items to your database name
    Dim view As New DataView(tables(0))
    source1.DataSource = view
    DataGridView1.DataSource = view
    'fin
End Sub



End Class
```

I want to add fontions (insert row from (Textbox1.Text/2/3) / delete row/modify row/save change to the database)
let's call every bouton to do an action (bouton 1/2/3/4)

[image]

Comment: Do you know that you can allow users to enter data into the DGV itself rather than provide separate controls for data entry?

Comment: uhm , can you explain me  with an example :-) ?

Comment: No, I cant.  There is nothing to explain.  Instead of typing "tel" data into that TextBox they can enter that data in the "Tel" column of the DGV.  You also dont need a new record button - that DGV row with the star (`**`) in the RowHeader **is** the new user row.

Comment: but i need to that with a dialog box . to use this command later in another ways , i need now only the command :/

Comment: i use actually Me.TestDataSet.Table1.Update(Me.TestDataSet.Table1) to save and that work perfectly . i need please help in add/del/rows